# how to change camera orientation from landscape mode to portrait mode in face recognition application

Tags: android

I am working face recognition application in which i need to keep my phone in landscape for detection and recognition of face and when i changed the orientation from landscape to portrait it only changed the screen orientation  image like this in image below...

How can i change it please help...

[These are the images after changing the orientation in landscape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Us9o7.png)
[These are the images after changing the orientation in portrait](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rctW.png)